# Get row and column pandas boolean dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a boolean `Pandas` dataframe (all the values are either `True` or `False`) and I need to get for each row the columns where the value is `True`.

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: `np.where(df)`? Otherwise you should provide a sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

use `[np.where(row)[0] for  index, row in df.iterrows()]`
it will produce a list of numpy arrays with indices of `True` values in each row. Add `.tolist()` for list of lists.

Stacking the resulting arrays is not possible because they may have various length.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True, False],[False,True],[True,True], [False,False]])
[np.where(row)[0].tolist() for  _, row in df.iterrows()]

[[0], [1], [0, 1], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

I managed to solve it with a loop for

Here is the code:

```
chbay = {}
for item in levels:
    baychan = convs[convs[item] == True]
    chbay[item] = baych[item]
```

Were convs is the name of the dataset and levels is a list of the column names of the dataset.

I am new in Python so probably my solution is not very tidy. I will try some of the ideas you have provide so I can learn new ways to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it drops all rows without a True match:

```
df.replace(False, np.NaN).dropna(how='all').replace(1.0, True).replace(np.NaN, False)
```

output:

```
     date  Amount   line   bool
4    True   False  False  False
8   False    True  False  False
9   False    True  False  False
11  False    True  False  False
12  False    True  False  False
13  False    True  False  False
14  False    True  False  False
```